# Localisation and Status Page Re-Execution lead to 404 instead of error page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, http-status-codes

I try to setup a asp.net core 2.0 MVC project with localisation in the url and status code pages with re-execution. I don't get it to work and I don't know where to start my debugging.

The project uses Windows Authentication and authorizes with AD groups.

My `Startup.cs` looks like this (I only post the Configure Method):

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Index", "?i_statusCode={0}"); //MARKUP 1


        IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
                new CultureInfo("de"),
                new CultureInfo("it"),
        };


        var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("de"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        };
        var requestProvider = new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider();
        localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, requestProvider);

        app.UseRouter(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapMiddlewareRoute("{culture=de}/{*mvcRoute}", subApp =>
            {
                subApp.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

                subApp.UseMvc(mvcRoutes =>
                {
                    mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{culture=de}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Note: If I change the `MARKUP1` line to `app.UseStatusCodePages();` everything works as intended - but I want to customize my error pages.

My `HomeController.cs` looks like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{    
        [Authorize(Roles = "NonExistingRole")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

My `ErrorController.cs` looks like this:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(int? i_statusCode=null)
    {
        var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();

        ViewBag.StatusCode = i_statusCode;
        ViewBag.OriginalPath = feature?.OriginalPath;
        ViewBag.OriginalQueryString = feature?.OriginalQueryString;

        return View();

    }
}
```

And My `Index.cshtml` (located in `/Views/Error/`) looks like this:

```
<p>Status Code: <b>@ViewBag.StatusCode</b></p>
<p>OriginalPath: <b>@ViewBag.OriginalPath</b></p>
<p>OriginalQueryString: <b>@ViewBag.OriginalQueryString</b></p>
```

When I call the Index Method of my Home Controller with Authorisation, everything works as intended. However if I do not have authorisation I would expect to see the error view, (correctly filled) - but instead I just get a HTTP 404 (blank page).

I am pretty sure that this problem comes from the localisation in the route. Because when I visit the website `http://localhost:52288/de/Error/Index?i_statusCode=404` manually I see the expected error view page. However if I navigate to `http://localhost:52288/Error/Index?i_statusCode=404` I also get the blank HTTP 404 (without page / view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the following Route below my default route in the `Startup.cs`:

```
mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                      name: "error",
                      template: "Error/Index",
                      defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", culture = "de" });
```

I don't think this is the best solution but so far it seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up custom error pages in your web.config file. For example:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Erros/Index?statusCode=404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />

</httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: regarding to every tutorial I found so far (e.g. https://andrewlock.net/re-execute-the-middleware-pipeline-with-the-statuscodepages-middleware-to-create-custom-error-pages/ or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1) I don't have to do sth like this... Actually I don't even have such a file locally (only on my live-environment, after I publish)